# Enabling/Disabling JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm developing a small photo editing application and would like the JButtons disabled until the user loads an image, at which point I want the buttons to become enabled(clickable). My thinking was to add a boolean imageFound, and an image checker method. If boolean is false, the buttons are disabled and if it is true they are enabled (the boolean is set to true in the load image actionPerformed method). The problem im having is that when running the app, the buttons are disabled as they should be, but when i load the image they would still be disabled. I dont know if maybe i am missing any piece of code to recheck whether the image is available, thus enabling the buttons (at runtime ofc). Thanks for any help.

```
...BufferedImage effects = null;
boolean bmpFound = false;


public GUI()
{        
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    this.initComponents();
    this.bmpChecker();
    this.addListeners();        
    this.setTitle("PicTweak");
    this.setSize(900, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

...else if(e.getSource() == loadItem)
    {            
        try
        {
            imagePath = DialogIO.displayOpenDialog();
            effects = ImageInOut.loadImage(imagePath);                
            imageHolder.setIcon(new ImageIcon(effects));
            bmpFound = true;
        }

....public void bmpChecker()
{
    if(bmpFound)
    {
        grayScale.setEnabled(true);
        blur.setEnabled(true);
        reset.setEnabled(true);
        brightDark.setEnabled(true);
        horFlip.setEnabled(true);
        verFlip.setEnabled(true);
        verHorFlip.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else 
    {
        grayScale.setEnabled(false);
        blur.setEnabled(false);
        reset.setEnabled(false);
        brightDark.setEnabled(false);
        horFlip.setEnabled(false);
        verFlip.setEnabled(false);
        verHorFlip.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about showing some code?

Comment: Some code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: -1 'some code' or 'code snippet'.  +1 [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you load/unload the image, call `bmpChecker()` afterwards, i.e.

```
...
try
{
    imagePath = DialogIO.displayOpenDialog();
    effects = ImageInOut.loadImage(imagePath);                
    imageHolder.setIcon(new ImageIcon(effects));
    bmpFound = true;
    bmpChecker();
}
...
```

A better alternative would be t add listeners for the image loading, i.e. for each control or group of controls that needs to update its state accordingly, you'd register a listener that is notified whenever an image is loaded or unloaded. The listener could then trigger the updates of the corresponding controls.

Something like:

```
class ImageEvent {
  private boolean imageLoaded; //plus getter/setter and maybe initialized in constructor
}    

interface ImageListener {
  void imageChanged(ImageEvent e);
}

...

List<ImageListener> listeners;

...

try
{
    imagePath = DialogIO.displayOpenDialog();
    effects = ImageInOut.loadImage(imagePath);                
    imageHolder.setIcon(new ImageIcon(effects));
    bmpFound = true;

    ImageEvent imgageEvent = new ImageEvent();
    imageEvent.setImageLoaded(true);

    for( ImageListener l : listeners ) {
      l.imageChanged(imageEvent);
    }
}

...
```

And an example listener:

```
class JButtonImageListener implements ImageListener {
   private JButton button; //plus getter/setter

   public void imageChanged(ImageEvent e) {
     button.setEnabled(e.isImageLoaded());
   }
}
```